# NRST Pin pull-up resistor on STM32F303RET6

Tags: datasheet, pullup, reset

The datasheet from the STM32F303RET6 shows that a pull-up resistor (a weak one?) is already included in the device itself. Rpu.

[image]

But my knowledge tells me I have to add one myself in front of NRST, along with the .1uF cap, but to VDD which is 3.3V in my system.

Based on this tutorial: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html and table 69 in [the datasheet of the STM32F303RET6](https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/stm32f303re-1851203.pdf) and the I<sub>IH</sub> of 400uA

- V<sub>IH</sub> = 0.445*Vdd = 0.445 * 3.3V = 1.4685V

I would need a pull-up resistance of (3.3 - 1.4684)V ⁄ 400uA = 4.57875kOhm
Is my observation correct? what would happen if I chose a resistor of higher value? Do I need this resistor or am I mis-interpeting the datasheet?

What is common knowledge on this subject?

Comment: What knowledge you have that implies an external pull-up is necessary?

Comment: Where did you get Iih of 400uA from?

Answer (score 2):

Just do as the datasheet tells you.

External resistor is not needed or even recommended any more.

If you want, you can have a place for the external pull-up, but leave the resistor off, unless for some reason you think it is needed.

Comment: Second'd.  I have designed with two different versions of the 303 and haven't placed a discrete pull-up for either.